# Trimming first 4 character from given table in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have table A in teradata which has column plancode .
Possible values of this plancode are

1. GNSC11Q
2. BNSC12Q
3. HNSC13Q
4. 12345
5. A1234

I want to remove first 4 character from string which has first 4 character like GNSC, BNSC and HNSC so the final values will be like 11Q, 12Q, 13Q.

I need update statement that will remove above mentioned first 4 char from all the data in that Plancode column. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And the last two rows result in `5` and `4`? `SUBSTRING(plancode FROM 5)`

Comment: Actually I need to remove 4 characters only for the string that has first 4 characters in (GNSC, BNSC and HNSC). SO last 2 results should be as it is 12345 and A1234

Comment: Add a WHERE-condition to filter those values: `UPDATE mytable SET plancode = SUBSTRING(plancode FROM 5) WHERE plancode LIKE ANY ('GNSC%',BNSC%','HNSC%')`

Comment: Great , thank you .